# “module 'socket.http' not found:” --Lua on iMac

Tags: macos, sockets, lua, luasocket

When I run my code in terminal, I get this error/message:

```
module 'socket.http' not found: 
    no field package.preload['socket.http'] 
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua' 
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua' 
    no file './socket/http.lua' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.so' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so' 
    no file './socket/http.so' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so' 
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so' 
    no file './socket.so'
```

Some sources led me to look into `LuaSocket`, but I still have no idea on what to do or how I would install that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several places where a guide to install LuaSocket is available. Some of them are listed as follows:

- http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/installation.html
- https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/tree/cvs-diego
- http://luarocks.org/

My preferred method would be to install [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org/) and then use the following command in terminal:

```
luarocks install luasocket
```

Answer (score 1):

A few more points. While configuring luarocks you may need to point to lua installation directory for example:
**./configure --with-lua=/opt/lua53/**

There are similar options:
--with-lua-bin
--with-lua-include
You can use any of these but make sure the desired directory structure is available in the directory you have mentioned!